# What are search_index & search_dataset tables for, can I clean them?

Tags: database, importing-exporting

I am trying to dump sql from local dev site to production server, I found that search_index & search_dataset these two tables are big, made the sql file really big.

I am guessing these two tables are about storing search indexes which I can always to re-index from scratch later. Correct me if wrong.

So **is it OK/safe to delete all the records of them**?  then export the database, import to my server. By doing this I can reduce the file size of dump file.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a quick note: You don't have to delete all the records and then export. If you use drush... do something like `drush sql-dump --structure-tables-list=search_index,cache,cache_form`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These tables are used by the site's search function, as provided by the core's Search module. They're built from your site's content, and the descriptions in code in [`search_schema()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--search--search.install/function/search_schema/7) say:

- **search_dataset** - "Stores items that will be searched"
- **search_index** - "Stores the search index, associating words, items and scores"

Though you can ignore/truncate the contents of these tables to keep your database dumps smaller, they will be recreated during cron runs as your site's content is re-indexed. Beware that rebuild times can be a lengthy if your site has a lot of content.

I've always found the [Backup and Migrate module](http://drupal.org/project/backup_migrate) to be much handier than command-line MySQL as tables and/or their contents can be ignored, plus do scheduled dumps and  have various export/import profiles.